# The tabs in the window GUI are not displayed correctly. It is displayed as text

Tags: 16.04

I am a new user running Ubuntu 16.04. I have an issue with the tabs in the window GUI. It is displayed as text instead of as tabs.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your problem further? Maybe provide a screenshot? It sounds like you mean the Unity panel. That's the Ubuntu equivalent to the Windows taskbar.

Comment: . It displays text of two tabs next to each other. For example All setting and  keyboard setting tabs are displayed as All SettingKeyboard Setting @ComputerLooker

Comment: I have added a photo but the community changed it to a link. Are you able to see my link in the post ? @ComputerLooker

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT91q.png

Comment: The community changed the link to inline because it so much easier for us to work with... having it all on one screen in one view.  As far as your links instead of buttons, I experienced this when I performed a force install of a package than changes a lot of my default libraries... I believe mainly the gtk libraries.  I worked long at trying to recover, including reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.  I ended up backing up my `etc`, and /var/lib/mysql` and other important directories and reinstalled Ubuntu.  It automatically reserved my `/home` and `/usr/local` folders.

Comment: Hopefully you'll have success with the community.  If not you might consider asking a question for the best method of reinstalling Ubuntu and preserving your important data and configurations.

Comment: @harishsai I see. I see you mean the tabs bar beneath the title bar. Like in the settings. Your buttons aren't clickable? I've got nothing for you on that. Really sorry! I would suggest grabbing all of your important files and saving them to a flash drive, then reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch. Because you are brand new, it shouldn't be very hard to do that considering you _just_ started, neither should you have very much stuff to move to the flash drive.

Comment: Have re-installed the ubuntu... Thanks for reviewing my problem. But i am not sure of the orgin. I have not done anything stupid at all. Just upgraded my packages . Not sure if i can do that in future or not . @L.D.James

Comment: I'm sorry the community doesn't have a resolution for this except reinstalling the OS.  That really should be a last resort.  I'll have to try to figure out how to reproduce the the issue so that I can spend more time trying to figure out a fix on a test machine.  If I get this figured out I'll come back to this question and put an answer for the community so that if it happens to someone else they will have a fix.  In the meantime, the experience in reinstalling Ubuntu and preserving your personal files and configurations can be a valuable experience.